# how to remove input type hidden fields xss and blind sql injection in Codeigniter 2.2.6?

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, hidden-field

we are using `Codeigniter 2.2.6` version . we have different forms in which we are using input hidden fields like below

```
<input type='hidden' value='<?php echo $user;?>'>
```

After the security tool run on the forms we are facing `XSS` and `Blind SQL` injection errors.
I have enabled xss in config file like below
`$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;`
 and also we are using the Active records. We are also using the codeigniter form validation rules.

please provide suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

`global_xss_filtering` prevent all the XSS Injection. So you are almost done.

Also when an input filed is there `$this->input->post()` and `$this->input->cookie()` and `$this->input->server()`. Bcz **this prevent SQL Injection**.

Read this [Input Class](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html) and  [Security Helper](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/security_helper.html)

Comment: Thank you for sharing information. we are using the xss_clean for input field but we are not loading the $this->load->helper('security');. Is it compulsory to load the security helper ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for sharing information. We are using the xss_clean for input field but we are not loading the $this->load->helper('security'); in individual controller or model instead we are auto loading the security helper like below
$autoload['helper'] = array('url','cookie','string','security');
Is it compulsory to load the security helper in every model or controller? Please suggest me to get out from security issues .